# SQL Exception - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm comparing a datetime variable to a `where` clause in a stored procedure. I have a problem with string literals. Any help is really appreciated

I get a conversion error in if loop while assigning `@PostingDttm` to where clause.

```
Declare @PostingDttm as DateTime
Declare @SqlQuery as nVarchar(Max)
Declare @WhereClause as varchar(1000)

Begin
    Set @PostingDttm = (select max(Posting_Dttm) from [salestable])
    Set @SqlQuery = N'Insert into dbo.table1
                      select * from dbo.table2'

    If(@PostingDttm Is Not Null)
    Begin
        Set @WhereClause = ' where posting_datetime > '+@PostingDttm+''
        Set @SqlQuery += @WhereClause
    End 

    EXEC (@SqlQuery)
End
```

Comment: Use Return after SET @PostingDttm = (SELECT max(Posting_Dttm) from [SalesTable]) and run your code. If you find same error again then this line is your problem...

Comment: :sniffles at what appears to be yet another dynamic SQL [ab]use:

Comment: Tanjim Rahman - If I use Return after my Select Statement, it says Command(s) completed successfully

Comment: There is a problem in Set @WhereClause = ' where posting_datetime > '+@PostingDttm+'' statement.

I might not be using the string literals properly

Comment: I've figured it out. Using Cast i've fixed my problem.. 

Set @WhereClause = ' where posting_datetime > '''+Cast(@PostingDttm as varchar(80))+''''